# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : ' is not a valid XML character

Tags: java, .net, encoding, decoding

I am calling .net webservice in JAVA class which will read string from text file and UTF8 encode that and return that string to JAVA .Some times the correct output is coming . but sometimes this is giving illegal argument exception eventhough the text in text file is in correct format .
 Below is the exception I am getting:

```
**SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet BaseController threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The char '0x0' after 'return code:  502
<HEAD><TITLE>Parent proxy is not responding</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Parent proxy is not responding</H1><HR>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: Parent proxy is not responding</B></FONT>
<HR>
<!-- default "Parent proxy is not responding" response (502) -->
</BODY>
' is not a valid XML character.
    at org.apache.axis.components.encoding.AbstractXMLEncoder.encode(AbstractXMLEncoder.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.xmlEncodeString(XMLUtils.java:131)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.DOM2Writer.normalize(DOM2Writer.java:344)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.DOM2Writer.print(DOM2Writer.java:246)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.DOM2Writer.print(DOM2Writer.java:208)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.DOM2Writer.serializeAsXML(DOM2Writer.java:77)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.DOM2Writer.serializeAsXML(DOM2Writer.java:60)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.DOM2Writer.nodeToString(DOM2Writer.java:49)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.privateElementToString(XMLUtils.java:433)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.ElementToString(XMLUtils.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.getInnerXMLString(XMLUtils.java:542)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.dumpToString(AxisFault.java:388)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.printStackTrace(AxisFault.java:789)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:451)
    at com.hcl.webservice.BaseController.doPost(BaseController.java:155)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
**
```

Please help in solving this problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The message says that the NULL-character (0x0) after the complete following string:

```
return code:  502
<HEAD><TITLE>Parent proxy is not responding</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Parent proxy is not responding</H1><HR>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: Parent proxy is not responding</B></FONT>
<HR>
<!-- default "Parent proxy is not responding" response (502) -->
</BODY>
```

is not a valid XML character. In other words, you are experiencing network problems involving the parent proxy, and the body of the HTTP response contains a human-readable description of the problem in HTML format. Your service client is trying to parse this text as XML and therefore your error.

Comment: Hi Marko, Thanks for your reply .I have removed the hexa decimal value of '  from the encoded string and its working fine without exception.